# want to count the total OBJECTS in **monthly_engagement_info**, it have 2 objects but i want to count progmattically

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

> want to count the total OBJECTS in **monthly_engagement_info**, it have 2 objects but i want to count progmattically.

```
  {

 "status": {

"monthly_engagement_info": [
  {

    "ride_description_title": "Home Address",
    "ride": "Home"

  },
  {      
    "ride_description_title": "Home Address"
  }
]
}

 }
```

Comment: You can convert it to json then jsonarray of `monthly_engagement_info` will be provide you size of array.

Comment: please explain how?

Comment: Log.d("engangmentlenth",""+jObject1.getString("monthly_engagement_info").length()

not work 
@DheerubhaiBansal

Answer (score 2):

```
    String response="you response";
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray arrayInfo=object.getJSONArray("monthly_engagement_info");
    Log.d(" size of info"," size= "+arrayInfo.length()); // here get size
```